# Testing with Cassandra during client development

Tags: java, cassandra

I come from a standard Java JPA/Hibernate development background. When I come to test/test against my DAO layer, I would normally configure an in memory database (HSQLDB) to replace interacting with a real database.

Is there an in-memory or lightweight version of Cassandra that could/should be used?

I have started to look a the DataStax Java Driver and it looks like I could build a testing framework to attach to a running Cassandra instance, build keystore, create schema insert data then drop keystore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can run an embedded cassandra in your unit tests. However, it is not fully  in-memory but still requires a place on a disk to create its data and tx log files. Have a look at [cassandra-unit](https://github.com/jsevellec/cassandra-unit) and the [examples](https://github.com/jsevellec/cassandra-unit-examples). If you google for cassandra-unit you will also find articles on how to combine it with a RAM disk to speed up things, etc.

Answer (score -1):

The (DataStax) Java driver API makes use of interfaces for much of its object references, so you can unit test some of your Cassandra manipulating code using mock objects that implement those interfaces. For example, you could unit test your code for processing the data returned by a query by mocking the `ResultSet` interface. That approach, however, would not enable you to check that your *queries* were correct.